# Can you use screen(1) with multiple TTYs to do low bandwidth console sharing?

Tags: ssh, ncurses, gnu-screen, tty, screensharing

Working in low bandwidth environments sometimes I need to share a text console (TTY) screen with a co-worker. I often use the screen(1) tool to keep multiple windows open in the same SSH connection and be able to reconnect and continue where I left off, when my connections drop due to bad internet. I wonder if we could not attach multiple SSH sessions / TTYs to the same screen(1) session so that my co-worker(s) and I can both use the same console? It should be possible, but is it?

Comment: It wouldn't work unless they're the same user.

Comment: @ThomasDickey and if they are the same user, would it work? How? That would be really cool, because in my use case we would operate as the same user.

Comment: The same user (has permissions) to attach from different terminals (on the same machine of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as follows:

1. first screen session is started with

   screen ...
2. then from another console as the same user someone else can attach to the same screen session with

   screen -x

And then they can both work, one thing typed by one will be visible by both, etc.

Note: if the screen session has multiple windows, then each attached terminal can switch to a different window independently.